# Can Indian developer upload paid apps on android market?

Tags: android

This question has been ask many times but I found its replies are around 1 year old.

What is current situation ?
Can Indian developer upload paid apps on android market ?

Or are there any alternative android app store available to upload paid apps ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would Indian developers specifically be not able to upload?

Comment: @GolezTrol :: Indian developers can upload apps but only free not paid This is what I heard.

Comment: what a strange question. where did you hear that?

Comment: Baseless question.Any developer can upload paid as well as free apps

Comment: Refer to site http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&&answer=150324

Comment: @AndroidKiller - Well - that is the correct question. India is not under supported merchants. http://goo.gl/tFMDv

Comment: they have lifted the ban have a look at this link http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/09/21/developers-from-india-can-now-sell-apps-in-the-play-store/