# Android Paid app availability on India?

Tags: android, google-play

I don't have a developer account in the Google play shop and I'd like to clarify paid app availability for the Android developer account in India or the price of an app in an Indian Android developer account?

Can help me get a paid app to publish from India?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions and answers.. Please read [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question for us?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra where how to ask this type of question?

Comment: @AndroSelva i am update my question pls,help me!

Comment: please check this link on how to publish paid apps from INDIA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305897/how-to-publish-paid-android-app-in-market-and-authorize-people-to-download/11306050#11306050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can purchase Paid app from india, but can't upload Paid app in market. Check this: [Supported locations for merchants](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324)

FYI, the page link you have given is itself contains:

> Paid App Availability => Priced applications are currently only
>   available to users in the following countries.

Can't you understand what its trying to say.

Still For more information check below Questions/Answers:

1. [Can Indian developer upload paid apps on android market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867826/can-indian-developer-upload-paid-apps-on-android-market)
2. [Android Publisher Account on Android Market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412281/android-publisher-account-on-android-market)